# Making a C++ dll support more than 64 processors - What is per-processor data structure

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I was reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/processor-groups) article and it states that

> If an application uses a DLL that has per-processor data structures,
> and the DLL has not been modified to support more than 64 logical
> processors, all threads in the application that call functions
> exported by the DLL must be assigned to the same group.

What does it mean for a dll to be modified to support more than 64 logical processors ?
My dll currently launches threads and uses `SetThreadGroupAffinity` to assign those threads to specific processors. My question is do I need to build my dll with a special flag ? What does modification here mean ?

Comment: The key here is "**per-processor** data structures". See [Per-Processor Data](http://www.1024cores.net/home/lock-free-algorithms/tricks/per-processor-data) for details. If your DLL is not creating and tracking data on a per-processor basis, vs a per-thread basis, then don't worry about this.

Comment: That quote is most likely referring to usage of the older functions such as `SetThreadAffinityMask`, which now includes the note "On a system with more than 64 processors, the affinity mask must specify processors in the thread's current processor group."  When that function was introduced there was no such thing as processor groups.

Comment: @RemyLebeau still a little confused on what per-processor means. The example uses SetThreadAffinityMask instead I am using `SetThreadGroupAffinity` which makes more sense.

Comment: Processors are organized in groups, up to a max of 64 processors per group. A given thread can have an affinity mask specifying which processors within the currently assigned group the thread is allowed to run on. `SetThreadAffinityMask()` can only specify processors within the currently assigned group. `SetThreadGroupAffinity()` can assign a new group, and the processors within that group. Software that needs to support more than 64 processors MUST be made group-aware so that it can access all available processors

Comment: What is confusing about PER-PROCESSOR vs PER-THREAD? Do you know what [thread-local storage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/thread-local-storage) is? Imagine something similar for CPU-local storage (not really a thing, from an API perspective). Create some data in your code and only let specific CPUs access specific elements, if you know which CPU your code is running on at any given time. For example, if you have  100 CPUs, create an array with 100 elements, where code running on CPU 0 only uses array element 0, code on CPU 1 only uses array element 1, and so on.

Comment: `SetThreadGroupAffinity()` allows threads of an application to access processors even if the application those threads reside in is launched in a different group (a group where those processors dont reside). My question is do I need to do anything different to my static dll if its using `SetThreadGroupAffinity` ?

Comment: There is nothing you need to do to the DLL itself, no. There is no flag you need to set. This is strictly a runtime API deal. If your DLL code needs to access higher CPUs, you simply assign a given thread to the appropriate processor group and let the OS schedule that thread to run on a CPU of that group.

Comment: The text you quoted doesn't apply to the actual act of creating threads, only to what those threads do once they are running.  What the text is saying is if you are using a DLL that creates data associated with each CPU, but it doesn't account for more than 64 CPUs being present, then obviously it can't create data for all possible CPUs, so the threads that call into the DLL have to be restricted to only the group(s) for CPUs the DLL is aware of (ie, likely only group 0). If the DLL is written to be group-aware, and can associate its data with more than 64 CPUs, then don't worry about this.